# Automatic show and hide multiple divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a variable amount of div's labelled "wrap" with a number

```
<div id="wrap0">Fixed text</div>
<div id="wrap1"></div>
<div id="wrap2"></div>
<div id="wrap3"></div>
```

Wrap0 is a fixed text, wrap 1 and following are generated from mysql php. I want to show wrap0 for certain amount of time, hide wrap0 and show the content of wrap1, hide wrap1 and show wrap0 again, hide wrap0 and show wrap 2 etc.

I have managed to toggle between them with an interval using jquery:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();    
$j(document).ready(function () {
        setInterval(function () {
            $j.fx.off = true
            $j('#wrap1').toggle('show');
            $j('#wrap0').toggle('hide');
        }, 3000);
    });
```

However, this only works for 2 div's. The amount of div's (wraps) is variable, it depends on the amount of rows in the mysql table.

I have looked at different scripts but can't figure out how to make this working automatic, most scripts work with a clickfunction, which hides $(this), which is the current div.

Does it make it easier if it toggles random?

Comment: @Alex - Probably a noConflict handle.

Comment: Yes it is, sorry I've added it to the script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$j(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(function () {
        $j.fx.off = true
        var wraps = $j('*[id^=wrap]');               // get the jQuery array of elements
        var currentWrap = $j('*[id^=wrap]:visible'); // get the currently visible wrap element
        var idx = Array.prototype.indexOf.apply(wraps, currentWrap); // get its index
        currentWrap.hide();                          // hide it
        var nextIndex = (idx+1) % wraps.length;      // calculate the next index while taking into consideration the maximum length of the wraps array
        var nextWrap = $j(wraps[nextIndex]);          // get the next element
        nextWrap.show();                             // show it
    }, 3000);
});
```

If the `#wrapN` elements don't change, you can move the `wraps` variable up one closure for performance improvement.

For selector information see the [official docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

## Edit

As pointed in the comments `indexOf` is not supported by IE8 or below, in that case you can use [`$.inAarray`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/):

```
var idx = $j.inArray(currentWrap, wraps);
```

Note: Again if wraps don't change, the solution from `jessegavin` is more performant.

Comment: Thank you for all the comments in the script, appreciate it!

However, it's still difficult for me to understand. I see you make an array of "wrap" but how do you know the index? Does it automatically sees the number as an index?

Comment: The line `Array.prototype.indexOf.apply(wraps, currentWrap);` will give you the index of `currentWrap` from within the array of `wraps`

Comment: Not sure whether this matters for the OP, but Array.prototype.indexOf isn't supported in IE8 or below.  jQuery.index() function could be used instead (if needed)

Comment: @jessegavin but does it matter, that both your answers do not switch between wrap0 and "wrap-next", but only switch for "wrap-next" and so on?

Comment: Wow works great! But I needed to change $(wraps[nextIndex]); to $j(wraps[nextIndex]);  because of the var $j = jQuery.noConflict(); but it's working like it should.

I think it's fine if it's not working in IE8 but thanks for the remark. I will look it up in the documentation in case it's not working anymore.

Comment: Updated the answer to correct `$j` & `indexOf` problem.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create an array of all your wrappers as well as way to keep track of your current position in the array.

Something like the following. [See a Demo](http://embed.plnkr.co/odfUMYgyvCvOIniV6UdT/preview)

```
$j(document).ready(function () {
    var wrappers = $j("[id^=wrap]").hide();
    var length = wrappers.length;
    var index = -1;
    setInterval(function () {
        next = index + 1;
        if (next === wrappers.length) {
          next = 0;
        }
        wrappers.eq(index).hide();
        wrappers.eq(next).show();
        index++;
        if (index == wrappers.length) {
          index = 0;
        }
    }, 3000);
});
```

Comment: shouldnt the selector be ^= ?

Comment: Wrap0 isn't shown in the beginning, it starts of at wrap1. For the rest the script works quite well.

Comment: I fixed that too. See the demo

Answer (score 0):

You could try something simple like:

```
<div id="wrap0">Fixed text0</div>
<div id="wrap1">Fixed text1</div>
<div id="wrap2">Fixed text2</div>
<div id="wrap3">Fixed text3</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
var i = 0;
var numberOfWraps = 3; //value from SQL query
for (var j = i+1; j<=numberOfWraps; j++){
    $('#wrap'+j).toggle('hide');
}
setInterval(function () {
    if (i !== numberOfWraps){
    $('#wrap'+(i+1)).toggle('show');
    $('#wrap'+i).toggle('hide');
    i = i+1;
    }
    else{
    $('#wrap'+numberOfWraps).toggle('hide');
    i = 0;
    $('#wrap'+i).toggle('show');    
    }
}, 3000);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

What you to do is assign a class to each div then control whether to hide or show with the class designation, not the ID.

```
<div id="wrap0" class="wrap"></div>

$j('.wrap').toggle('show');
```

Comment: Does this matter? I can choose if I want to hide/show on ID or on class right? 

I don't see how it solves hide/show dynamic generated divs.